# Sql Server query problem in Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have Table Job in which i have a column name MainJob_Id name
So i just want to Update Container_TypeId Column Value as 1,2,3...go on...
when MainJob_id is same...

else MainJob_id is new then start again as 1

[image]

Execpted Result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ContainerTypeId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MainJob_Id ORDER BY LengthId DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET ContainerTypeId = rn;
```

However, you might want to not do this update and instead just select the sequence you want at the time you query.

Comment: @akhileshsingh . . . You should accept this answer if it works for you.